# Racket - arguments for procedure how to get all

Tags: racket

I need to write procedure for calculation of weighted sum in follow functionality:

```
((weighted-sum 1) 5)
5
((weighted-sum 1/2 1/2) 3 1)
2
```

etc..

So far I did only how to get parameters for procedure:

```
(define (weighted-sum x . xn) (cons x xs))
(weighted-sum 2 3)
> '(2 3)
```

How to get ((weighted-sum 2 3) **X X**) parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have one easy answer. It sounds like you're supposed to write a function that accepts a sequence of weights, and returns a function that accepts a sequence of weights, and sums the products of the weights and the sums (by the way, stating this yourself would have been really helpful...).

1) Is this your design, or someone else's? I would not design this function this way.

2) You can write functions that return functions in a bunch of different ways. E.g.:

```
;; these all do the same thing.
;; they all have the type (number -> (number -> number))

(define a (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y))))

(define ((a x) y) (+ x y))

(define (a x)
    (define (b y) (+ x y))
    b)
```

Answer (score 0):

So `weighted-sum` takes a variable number of values as parameters (let's call them `ws`) , and returns a new procedures that, in its turn, takes a variable number of parameters (`vs`) and does the calculation.
In racket, the `for/fold` construct comes in handy:

```lisp
(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (lambda vs
    (for/fold ((res 0)) ((i (in-list ws))
                         (j (in-list vs)))
      (+ res (* i j)))))
```

or even

```lisp
(define ((weighted-sum . ws) . vs)
  (for/fold ((res 0)) ((i (in-list ws))
                       (j (in-list vs)))
    (+ res (* i j))))
```

Alternatively, using a more classic `foldl` returning a named inner procedure:

```lisp
(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (define (sub . vs)
    (foldl
     (lambda (i j res) (+ res (* i j)))
     0
     ws
     vs))
  sub)
```

For any of those:

```
> ((weighted-sum 1) 5)
5
> ((weighted-sum 1/2 1/2) 3 1)
2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Last one question how to get length of in-lists?

Comment: You can use `(length ws)` and `(length vs)` but why would you need that?

Comment: I need it only for comparation of their lengths, I know that for result has difference zero impact.